# Mocking the window object for AngularJS unit tests

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, requirejs

I am trying to write a unit test for an AngularJS directive (which is wrapped in an module for requiring via requirejs), loading modules with `requirejs`, but I'm having issues with the global `window` object when loading in `angular`.

My current understanding is that I need to instantiate an angular app, add my directive to it, and then get the angular compiler to run on some HTML which contains the directive name. From that point on, I can test as usual.

However, when try to require `angular` in my test, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Evaluating c:\...\angular.js as module "angular" failed with error: ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

Some people suggested installing jsdom in order to get a window object, but from the error message above, you might be able to work out that I'm in a Windows environment and that combination seems to be painful.

At the moment, my test is simple:

```
// Imports, including requirejs config

describe("Directive tests", function() {
    var angular;
    before(function(done) {
        requirejs(['angular'], function(a) {
            angular = a;
        });
    });
});
```

I could go down the route of defining a `window` module in requirejs and have a mock version injected in the tests, but that seems like a lot of work.

Answer (score 1):

The [$window](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window) service is here for this purpose. Just inject it where needed.

From the documentation :

```
angular.module('windowExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window) {
        $scope.greeting = 'Hello, World!';
        $scope.doGreeting = function(greeting) {
        $window.alert(greeting);
    };
}]);
```

Comment: But this error is happening when try to require angular, I can't get as far as injecting a service. Angular is defined in the requirejs config map, so needs to be loaded as I have it above, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Unit tests should, by definition, test the unit in isolation from everything else. You should not need a window for it, or to `require` much of anything.

For example, here is a directive unit tests that launches a "confirm" popup. It uses mocha, but you could use jasmine or whatever you want.

```
    describe('confirm', function(){
        var element, scope, msg = "Are you sure?", html = 'ABC', spy, stub;
        beforeEach(function () {
            var self = this;
            stub = sinon.stub();
            self.$modal = {
                open: function () {
                    return {
                        result: {
                            then: stub
                        }
                    };
                }
            };
            spy = sinon.spy(self.$modal,"open");

            mod('GP.directives',{$modal:self.$modal});
            inject(function ($compile,$rootScope) {
                element = angular.element(html);
                scope = $rootScope;
                scope.foo = sinon.spy();
                $compile(element)(scope);
                scope.$digest();
                element.triggerHandler('click');
                scope.$digest();
            });
        });
        it('should call $modal.open when click the element', function(){
            spy.calledOnce.should.be.true;
        });
        it('should set up with "then"', function(){
            stub.calledOnce.should.be.true;
        });
        it('should have a single function argument to "then"', function(){
            stub.firstCall.args[0].should.be.type("function");
        });
        it('should not call the action when click the element', function(){
            scope.foo.called.should.be.false;
        });
    });
```

Notice that the only things the directive interacts with are:

- `$modal` - OK, I stubbed that out
- the html, which I passed in using `$compile(angular.element(html))`

This allows me to test it completely in isolation. It should be extremely rare that you actually need a `window` object to unit test something.